# Send mail with priority from console

Tags: debian, email, terminal

How can I send mail from the console marked with "priority high" flag?

Currently I'm using this syntax:

```
echo "message content" | mail -s "subject" user@example.com
```

I don't see any switches for this in `man`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30599/setting-headers-using-the-bin-mail-command

Comment: If you are sending mail to local users, maybe a `man write` made your day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `sendmail`? If so:

```
mymachine $ sendmail user@example.com <<EOM
> To: user@example.com
> From: me@example.com
> Subject: Test mail `date +"%x %H:%M"`
> Importance: high    
> X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
> X-MSMail-Priority: High
> 
> Test message
> EOM

mymachine $
```

The text after `>` would be typed in on the newline. Of course, you could just pipe a text file:

```
mymachine $ cat > message
> To: user@example.com
> From: me@example.com
> Subject: Test mail `date +"%x %H:%M"`
> Importance: high
> X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
> X-MSMail-Priority: High
> 
> Test message
## CTRL+D ##

mymachine $ cat message | sendmail user@example.com
```